# android listview getting correct icons

Tags: android, listview, icons

I have ListView with icons. Every ListView row either has a different icon or or doesn't have an icon.

I am able to get correct icons for rows which should have them but problem is, in rows where there shouldn't be any icon there is some icon.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        TextView title = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.name);
        ImageView icon = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.icon);

        HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();
        item = data.get(position);

        String imgPath = ASSETS_DIR + item.get(myTable.KEY_PIC) + ".png";

            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(vi
                        .getResources().getAssets().open(imgPath));
                icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        title.setText(item.get(myTable.KEY_NAME));

    return vi;
}
```

`KEY_PIC` always has a value and if `KEY_PIC`'s value is equal to some icon's filename only then it should show icon. I cant figure out how to code it. I should do something in if-else i guess.

Comment: Why does a row's "KEY_PIC" have a value if the row shouldn't have an icon set? Which value is it? If it's a valid path, an icon will be set. Did you check that there's no default source set in your layout xml which holds the 'icon' ImageView?

Comment: My xml layout dont have default source.

Comment: "KEY_PIC" is used to find other things in my project(same name but different location) So i dont have to add more information in my xml resource file(database).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you've done a bad thing by putting `HashMap<String, String> item = new HashMap<String, String>();` in your getView(). Right now you're making a new one of these for every row re-shown and that's unneeded. just delete it and use:

```
String imgPath = ASSETS_DIR + data.get(position).get(myTable.KEY_PIC) + ".png";
```

Quite honestly i can't understand how it is that you see an icon if you claim that your path doesn't lead to anything if the row isn't supposed to be showing something. If it worked well, then you could simply catch the exception that might occur upon setting and do nothing with it. Looking into the actual value of `data` at that position should yield insight. if it were me, i'd just put `null` at those positions.

A temporary alternative solution is to make a boolean array for each of the positions in your listview and then only perform your icon setting if the value at that position checks out.

```
boolean[] varIcon = {
            true, 
            false, 
            false, 
            true,
            false,
            true };
// ...
// then in the getView() now;


if (varIcon[position] == true) {
                String imgPath = ASSETS_DIR + data.get(position).get(myTable.KEY_PIC) + ".png";
                 try {
                        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(vi
                                .getResources().getAssets().open(imgPath));
                        icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

The likely problem is that the views are getting recycled and you're never clearing the image that was previously set, try this to prove it:

```
        String imgPath = ASSETS_DIR + item.get(myTable.KEY_PIC) + ".png";

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(vi
                    .getResources().getAssets().open(imgPath));
            icon.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            icon.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
```

However, relying on exception handling for a perfectly valid outcome is not a good practice (nor performance friendly). I would recommend you make your myTable.KEY_PIC column return null, and then you can do:

```
 String imageName = item.get(myTable.KEYP_PIC);
 if (imageName == null) {
   icon.setImageDrawable(null);
 } else {
   //your code
 }
```

Which is much cleaner.